# sql server shortcut for select statement writing

Tags: sql, sql-server

Many times a day I have to write similar queries to get single record:

```
select t.*
from some_table t
where t.Id = 123456
```

maybe there is some shortcuts for retrieving single record? Like entering id, table and SQL server generates rest code automatically

Comment: I use http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/ which allows you to create snippets, e.g. type "ssf" and it expands to "select * from". You can also use PhraseExpress which is not specific to SSMS but applies across Windows

Answer (score 1):

In Sql Server Go to

> Tools-> Options-> Environments->Keyboard

[image]

You will get shortcuts, there you can define your own as well as get the standards.

Answer (score 0):

you can set a short cut for a fully executable query like

```
select * from table where id =20
```

but not like below

```
select * from
```